# Invoke another bean's method in @PostConstruct raised a null pointer ex

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I am using Spring4.

There are three beans:`bean1` and `bean2` and `bean3`,and in my bean1's `@PostConstruct` method,i invoke bean2's method,this method of `bean2` will invoke bean3's method,and i got a NPE, beacuse method in `bean2` is invoked, `bean3` hasn't been injected yet.

How to avoid this kind of situation? The code looks something like this:

```
@Service
public class Bean1 {
    @Autowired
    private Bean2 bean2;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // invoke bean2's method
        bean2.test();
    }

}

@Service
public class Bean2 {
    @Autowired
    private Bean3 bean3;

    public void test() {
        // invoke bean3's method,got a null pointer ex,because bean3 is null.
        bean3.xxx();
    }
}
```

Comment: Move to constructor injection instead of field injection.

Comment: @M.Deinum Does Spring inject Bean2 into Bean1  before satisfying Bean2 dependencies in this case?

Comment: Yes, as `Bean2` might still be under-construction, as it is. With constructor injection this cannot be as the constructor needs to be fulfilled. It is also a general recommendation to favor constructor injection over field injection.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot.

Comment: It does work when i move to constructor injection instead of field injection. In addition,I built a simple spring project to simulate this situation and got no exception,so does this have anything to do with the order in which the beans are loaded.@M.Deinum

Comment: When using field injection, you might endup with a bean in your class that is still under construction. Spring does try to get the order right, however with field injection you can get a half initialized bean as it is harder to determine the dependencies. With constructor injection this isn't possble., as you cannot create  an object without that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

What Ever code posted by you, I don't thing you may get any problem.
Just Check in your whole code you are creating bean yourself not by spring its only one case.

If you are creating bean yourself then spring wont be inject anything and provide bean object as null. post

Comment: It did happen in my project. I am using springjpa and  Bean3 is a customized Repository  class extends `CrudRepository`.I don't know if that has anything to do with it.In addition,I built a simple spring project to simulate this situation and got no exception...So I'm confused right now.

Comment: how could you use extend instead on implements crudRepository please show your bean3 class

Comment: public interface xxRepository extends CrudRepository. [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need the `@DependsOn` annotation to make sure bean initialization happens in the order you expect.